# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while exporting data using mysql select query

Tags: mysql

This is the query I'm running in `PhpMyAdmin`.

```
SELECT 
    name,mobile,email,address
FROM
    customer
WHERE
  status = 'Active' 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/active_customers.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

And getting this error:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: And which part of the error you don't understand?

Comment: User **root** has full access over database. And all other queries like insert, update, delete, select are working fine just this one export query getting failed

Comment: The error is because you are running the query as lptool_app user and not root.  As was stated in another answer, if you wish to use the lptool_app user, then you need to give it the correct privileges in MySQL to do the work.  Else, you need to run the query as root user or other use with correct privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have permission to query `SELECT FROM CUSTOMER`. In order to fix this (assuming you have SSH access) :

1. Connect to MySQL server using SSH using a user which has access (or owns) MySQL :
   `ssh mysql@your_mysql_server.com`
2. Login to MySQL server as root with password:

   `mysql -u root -p`
3. Grant required permissions to the user you want (check the available permissions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html)):

   `GRANT [ALL/SELECT/etc..] ON database.table TO 'lptool_app'@'localhost';`
4. After finishing granting the privileges you want, It's best practice to reload all of the privileges:

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. You can check the privileges granted to any user using this command :

   `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'server';`
6. Using a privileged user (like `root`), you can run the same queries with PHPMyAdmin as well.
7. **NOTE: The permissions are granted to user@machine, not user only** so, if you grant your permissions to a specific user@machine, your user won't have the same permissions from another machine. But if you are only working from PHPMyAdmin, as it runs on a server, your machine won't change, therefore you should not be having problems.